# Visual Cobol 2012 and Nuget

Tags: nuget, cobol, cobol.net

I'm developing a DLL using Visual Cobol 2.2, and I want to make it a NuGet package so that other people in my shop can leverage it.  In my VC project, the first time I tried to do this, I right-clicked on References and clicked on "Manage NuGet Packages."  I received a message along the lines of "Not compatible with project."  Not sure of the exact message text because I only got it once.  After that, if I right-click on References, I do not even get the "Manage NuGet Packages" option.  If I try to add the Nuget package at the solution level, I get a message "...could not be installed because it is not compatible with any project in the solution."

What am I missing?  Is there something I need to do to the project properties for it to support NuGet?  Something with the NuGet configuration?  Something to the VC config?

Thanks for the help,

Mike